# LumX button (lx-button) won't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, lumx

I'm writing a web application using **HTML**, **Javascript** and **AngularJS**. For my UI I'm experimenting with **LumX**. I tried **Angular Material** but it was way too slow on IE.

However, I'm having difficulty simply submitting a form using LumX. The reason is I can't get the button to work. The LumX site clearly states:

"lx-button is a directive that create a link element if you specify a href or ng-href attribute
Otherwise, it creates a button element."

Here's what I have:

```
<lx-button id="add_button">Button</lx-button>
```

Then, in my **functions.js** file I have:

```
document.getElementById('add_button').addEventListener('click', add);
```

The **add( )** function simply adds that item to a list. The function is working, because the program works as intended with a normal button. It's just when I use the **lx-button** tag that it stops working.

Thanks.

Comment: You're choosing to use AngularJs and you're not using `ng-click`?

Comment: @Ankh - Thank you. This bit of code is from before I started to implement AngularJS. I'm also quite inexperienced using AngularJS, in fact this is my first time using it. Can you provide some code of how I should implement `ng-click` with this button and then use it to activate my `add()` function?

Comment: Try `<lx-button id="add_button" ng-click="add()">Button</lx-button>` assuming `add()` is available in the current `$scope`

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing that correctly. Here's what I have in my **.js** file: `angular.module('KBTM_App',['lumx']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {`. What would be the correct way to write the `add()` function in the scope?

Comment: @Ankh - Never mind, I managed to make it work. Thank you for your help. The button now works with `ng-click`!